# What is the meaning of "in a white light"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "in a white light" in the following sentences,

> Long long ago an Emperor lived in China. His name was Ming Ti. And the
>   Emperor had a son. His name was Ming Cho.  One day Ming Cho was
>   playing in the garden. There was a big storm. Lightning came down to
>   the garden **in a white light**.

(Source: Once There Was a Dog by EDWARD W. DOLCH and MARGUERITE P. DOLCH)
?

Does it mean "Lighten came down to the garden. The garden was filled with a white light."?

or does it mean "Lighten came down to the garden. the color of the garden
is a white light."?

Does "in" of "in a white light" mean "was filled with" ?

Comment: It does not mean the garden was filled with white light. I just means that there was a white light, probably a quick flash, as lightning is.

Comment: If so, does "Lightning came down to the garden in a white light" mean "Lightning came down to the garden. A white light was in the garden" ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not really sure what you are asking, Yes there was a white light in the garden. It would have lit everything up in the garden in a bright light - that is what lightning does. Can you please clarify what it is you are asking?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have known that the meaning of the preposition "in" is often used to indicate a place or a time. but, It is hard to understand when the prepositions "in" are used in different meanings. What it is I am wondering is the meaning of "in" in the sentence, "Lightning came down to the garden in a white light". does it mean "Lightning came down to the garden with a white light"? does "in" of the sentence mean "with" ?

Comment: Wow you are testing my own understanding of English! It could mean the same thing as "Lightning came down to the garden "as" a white light". Frankly I don't understand the concept of lightning "coming" down. Lightning strikes, and then it's done. There is no special meaning of "in" here, other than "in" can give more of a meaning of in you, or inside you possibly. It can imply a more personal feeling than "as" or "with".

Comment: Most English prepositions have many different possible usages. See entry number 4 in the Oxford dictionary. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in **(often followed by a noun without a determiner) expressing a state or condition.**

Comment: Yes @JavaLatte it is crazy how many uses "in" has! I never realized.

Comment: @wavery: ... and 'in' probably has fewer usages than many other prepositions.

Comment: If so(==>"in" is expressing a state or condition), does "Lightning came down to the garden in a white light" mean "Lightning came down to the garden, of which the state is a white light" ? Would it be ok to interpret this way when interpreting?

Comment: @user22046 'of which the state is a white light" sounds like it applies to the garden, but "in a white light" probably is intended to describe the lightning, "the state of the lightning is white light" (as if we didn't already know that). The writer was probably aiming for interesting, rather than clear, prose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visually, when [lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning) strikes, it often appears—very briefly—to come down from the sky to the ground. After that, also briefly, it appears as a coruscating solid line. It also looks white.

So, *lighting came down to the garden* is just a poetic way of saying *lightning struck (close to) the garden.* In other words, the bolt of lightning descended from the sky to the garden.

*In a white light* is the colour of the lightning itself that's being described. Although, at the moment of the flash, it will likely also brighten the surrounding area—especially if it's very close to the observer.

Comment: *Poetic* is the key word here. The questioner wants an interpretation of "in" that precisely gives the intended meaning, but there isn't one. The meaning simply has to be guessed from *lightning* and *white flash*, without help from the preposition.

Comment: I agree @Anonymous. Why so much focus on "in". It could have been "as" or "with". The questioner needs to explain his focus on "in" better or just accept the answers we have given.